Android Studio's scratch files are not fully supported in Kotlin 2.0
How can I bypass Android Studio's restriction on scripting in Kotlin 2.0 when using scratch files? Android Studio Ladybug 2024.2.1 displays the following message at the top of the Code Editor:
//    K2 mode: Kotlin scripting is not fully supported.


That warning isn't bogus; there's two options available:

wait for this issue to be closed: KT-58635
K2: Support Kotlin Scripting.
use Kotlin version 1.9.25 instead.


Just ignore the warning. Think this is the K2 mode of the IDE, which can also disabled entirely. Kotlin script nevertheless runs. Even with K2 enabled, some things with run on 1.9 ...the latest version is not always the most suitable.

And it's not about scratch files, but about *.kts. I'd assume *.kt shouldn't show the warning.
